# lm-sensors, what's the difference between "max" and "crit" temperature?

Tags: 20.04, overheating, temperature, lm-sensors

running `sensors -j -u` i get, among other things,

```
{
   "coretemp-isa-0001":{
      "Adapter": "ISA adapter",
      "Core 0":{
         "temp2_input": 68.000,
         "temp2_max": 85.000,
         "temp2_crit": 95.000,
         "temp2_crit_alarm": 0.000
      }
   }
}
```

what's the difference between the "max" (85c) and "crit" (95c) temperatures?

this part of the output is for the CPU, and the CPU in question is [Intel Xeon E5620](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/47925/intel-xeon-processor-e5620-12m-cache-2-40-ghz-5-86-gt-s-intel-qpi.html)

(i could GUESS that the "max" temp is where it starts thermal-throttling, and the "crit" temp is where it shuts down, but that's just a guess.)

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: @David sorry didn't know, it's 20.04